# Correctly call matlab dll from asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, matlab, dll, webforms

Recently I've been starting with Asp.net, particularly Web Form application. And in the application, I need to reference a dll produced by Matlab deploytool (including a .m function I wrote myself). 
I copied all relevant dlls to the Bin directory, add reference in the application and using the corresponding namespace. The compiler works fine but a TypeInitializationException was thrown in runtime when trying to initialize an instance of my matlab class.

BTW, in a Windows Form application it works fine amazingly, but not in Web Form applcation. Is there anything I missed when calling a matlab dll? e.g. Add XML comment in Web.config ?

Here is the key code from where the exception was thrown:

```
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
using diseases;  //this is the namespace of urinary_bladder created by deploytool

...

    MWArray [] value = new MWArray[8];  // This statement works well
    urinary_bladder ub = new urinary_bladder();  // A 'TypeInitializationException'   was thrown here
```

I'll appreciate any of your replies, thx a lot.

Comment: Does it make a difference, which WebServer you use? IIS or IIS Express? Does it only work on some machines or throw anytime? What .NET Version is used?